# TeamCity vs Team Build

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, tfsbuild

What's pro/cons between TeamCity and Team Build and why choose one instead of the other ?

Answer (score 4):

Interesting question. I've been using both systems quite a lot for building c# applications.

TeamCity

- Easy to use
- Beautiful
- Easy to install and set up
- Easy to extend and customize builds
- Interacts with other systems easily such as git, svn, JIRA and many, many more.

Team Foundation Build

- If you already have TFS set up, it's easy to get a build running
- Simple cases like building a solution is easy to set up
- Works smoothly together with TFS task management and source control.
- Cumbersome and ugly UI

All in all the Team (Foundation) Build can get the job done, but I prefer TeamCity.

Answer (score 3):

**[TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/)**

- Pros

  - Free (Charging doesn't commence until 20 users)
  - Supports multiple platforms (Ruby, Java, .NET)
  - Supports multiple source control systems
  - Supports multiple build runners (Rake, MSBuild, Nant, Ant)
  - Excellent reporting options
- Cons

  - Requires a Java stack (assuming you're a .NET shop)

**[Team (Foundation) Build](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181710%28VS.80%29.aspx)**

- Pros

  - Integrated solution with Microsoft dev stack
- Cons

  - Requires Team Foundation Server ($$$, though Gold Partners get 25 seats free and most other programmes give 5 seats (but you pay for 6 when you add another))
  - Only MSBuild supported

Comment: Are you sure Team City requires a Java stack? I was under the impression it supported Visual Studio.

Comment: It does support Visual Studio. It also runs on a Java stack.

Comment: @The Matt: It supports Visual Studio, but the SERVER runs Java

Comment: Actually it doesn't matter that server runs in Java. TC installs its own copy of jdk and you as a user is isolated from "Java".

Comment: I also don't see a big problem with TeamCity requiring JVM... for us it was never an issue, neither in performance terms nor in any other

Answer (score 1):

If your environment sports a few other opensource/free tools (SVN etc) and utilities I would tend towards choosing TeamCity. We have found it to be pretty cool and integrates with most other popular tools.

If you are "restricted" to MS stack (like you use VSS for source control) then that's the only really compelling reason to go with Team Build.

Comment: If you're using VSS still, you need to **GET OFF IT**.  Choose at least Subversion, possibly Mercurial if your devs can grok it!  :)